# minimum requirement to add posts via database

Tags: posts, bulk-import

I have a theme with a custom post type that is a business listing. I need to import a pack of business listings. I have written sql that adds the data to wp_posts and wp_postmeta. When I run my queries the posts show in the post edit screen in the admin but the page will not display until i press the 'update' button. The 'update' button is changing something in the db that i am missing. Are there any other tables that I would need to update?

```
$step1 = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT listing_id, `company name`, `primary sic description` FROM ap_listing', ARRAY_A);

foreach($step1 as $s1){
    $pname = $s1['company name'];
    $pname = str_replace(" ", "-", $pname);

    $wpdb->insert( wp_posts, 
        array(
            'listing_idp' => $s1[listing_id],
            'post_title' => $s1['company name'],
            'post_name' => $pname,
            'post_content' => $s1['primary sic description'],
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'post_type' => 'item',
            'comment_status' => 'closed',
            'ping_status' => 'closed',
            'post_author' => '2',
            'post_date' => '2016-10-13 14:07:04',
            'post_date_gmt' => '2016-10-13 19:07:04',
            'post_modified' => '2016-10-13 14:07:04',
            'post_modified_gmt' => '2016-10-13 19:07:04'
        )
    );




    $guid1 = 'http://spfpxnew.staging.wpengine.com/?post_type=item&#038;p=';
    $guid2 = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT id FROM wp_posts WHERE listing_idp = $s1[listing_id]", ARRAY_A);
    $guid2 = $guid2[0][id];
    $fix_guid = $guid1 . $guid2;

    $wpdb->update( wp_posts, 
        array( 'guid' => $fix_guid ),
        array( 'id' => $guid2 )
    );
}

//post_title post_name guid post_content post_type
//http://spfpxnew.staging.wpengine.com/?post_type=item&#038;p=6
$step2 = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT id, listing_idp FROM wp_posts', ARRAY_N);

foreach($step2 as $s2){
    if($s2[1] != ''){
        echo ' '.$s2[0].' '.$s2[1];
        $wpdb->update( ap_listing, 
            array(
                'id' => $s2[0]
            ),
            array( 'listing_id' => $s2[1] ) 
        );
    }
}
////////

$step3 = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT id, address, city, state, `zip code`, `web address`, `phone number` FROM ap_listing', ARRAY_A);


foreach($step3 as $s3){
    $s3zip = substr($s3['zip code'],0,5);
    $address = $s3[address].', '.$s3[city].', '.$s3[state].' '.$s3zip;
    $phone_number = $s3['phone number'];
    $web_address = $s3['web address'];


$wpdb->query("INSERT INTO wp_postmeta
                (post_id, meta_key, meta_value)
            VALUES
                ($s3[id], 'jv_item_address', '$address'),
                ($s3[id], 'jv_item_phone', '$phone_number'),
                ($s3[id], 'jv_item_website', '$web_address'),
                ($s3[id], 'jv_item_lat', '33.0415765'),
                ($s3[id], 'jv_item_lng', '-96.71691829999997'),
                ($s3[id], 'javo_control_options', ''),
                ($s3[id], 'javo_slider_type', ''),
                ($s3[id], 'javo_posts_per_page', ''),   
                ($s3[id], 'javo_item_tax', 's:17:\"a:1:{i:0;s:0:\"\";}\";'),
                ($s3[id], 'javo_blog_tax', ''),
                ($s3[id], 'javo_item_terms', 's:2:\"N;\";'),
                ($s3[id], 'javo_blog_terms', 's:2:\"N;\";'),
                ($s3[id], '_vc_post_settings',  'a:1:{s:10:\"vc_grid_id\";a:0:{}}'),
                ($s3[id], '_edit_lock', '1476225539:2'),
                ($s3[id], '_edit_last', '3'),
                ($s3[id], 'javo_this_featured_item', ''),
                ($s3[id], 'jv_item_email', ''),
                ($s3[id], 'jv_item_street_lat', '32.78092141476407'),   
                ($s3[id], 'jv_item_street_lng', '-97.29449262685023'),
                ($s3[id], 'jv_item_street_heading', '0'),
                ($s3[id], 'jv_item_street_pitch', '0'),
                ($s3[id], 'jv_item_street_zoom', '1.0000000000000002'),
                ($s3[id], 'video', ''),
                ($s3[id], 'detail_images', 's:2:\"N;\";'),
                ($s3[id], 'header_custom_frame', ''),
                ($s3[id], 'item_map_positon', 's:6:\"a:0:{}\";'),
                ($s3[id], 'item_map_type', 's:6:\"a:0:{}\";'),
                ($s3[id], 'rating_average', '0.0'),
                ($s3[id], 'rating_meta', 'a:3:{s:5:\"total\";i:0;s:5:\"count\";i:0;s:7:\"average\";s:3:\"0.0\";}'),
                ($s3[id], 'slide_template', 'default'),
                ($s3[id], 'id5d4b82bf8ac903deb7f1f2e0bffd8afd', '|'),
                ($s3[id], 'id760f1150c15bf1468167d6da636782b5', ''),
                ($s3[id], 'ide8fdcf7960dd73144a1b8c10b9472fcb', ''),
                ($s3[id], 'id1d5e239e8dd52aeec7d0cf048655fa94', ''),
                ($s3[id], 'idd979148b7f50be8daf3690ec24689468', 'one-basic'),
                ($s3[id], 'iddda96d13c08720696764b65c4e4ab1e8', '|'),
                ($s3[id], 'hours', ''),
                ($s3[id], '_hours', 'field_57a8ba1d84241'),
                ($s3[id], '_', 'field_57a8ba7584242'),
                ($s3[id], 'monday', ''),
                ($s3[id], '_monday', 'field_57a8c712e71f0'),
                ($s3[id], 'tuesday', ''),
                ($s3[id], '_tuesday', 'field_57a8ccb2df031'),
                ($s3[id], 'wednesday', ''),
                ($s3[id], '_wednesday', 'field_57a8ccb2df030'),
                ($s3[id], 'thursday', ''),
                ($s3[id], '_thursday', 'field_57a8ccb1df02f'),
                ($s3[id], 'friday', ''),
                ($s3[id], '_friday', 'field_57a8ccb1df02e'),
                ($s3[id], 'saturday', ''),
                ($s3[id], '_saturday', 'field_57a8ccaedf02d'),
                ($s3[id], 'sunday', ''),
                ($s3[id], '_sunday', 'field_57a8cca7df02c'),
                ($s3[id], 'id2a4db98f077d53cf4174811e3c0bc545', '|'),
                ($s3[id], '_thumbnail_id',  ''),
                ($s3[id], 'id0f0959cbade4391cb8a30aef3eb57204', ''),
                ($s3[id], 'id9748bd65165e381e97385e1b5da02eab', ''),
                ($s3[id], 'id4be8dc375419760b821506f6a910d839', ''),
                ($s3[id], 'id80b7c6af2fb8b382b30af29bd0173b1c', ''),
                ($s3[id], 'id27daa11ffa9b4d39eba88be248c2b6f2', ''),
                ($s3[id], 'idd74cc17ebbcaeaa64521e8348658aaff', ''),
                ($s3[id], 'idb87e03157e07dcac499c8abcb7f6fc62', '')
            ");

}
```

Comment: Use WordPress higher level functions for saving posts and meta. They'll look after everything for you.